# windows search bar background gets white even when is in dark mode

Tags: windows-10, windows-search, regedit

after disabling web search suggestions in windows search/start menu by regedit per that tutorial:

**edit explanation**:

```
windows is in dark mode, and this background is dark in dark mode, but it is not
```

after doing the procedure below it just turns white:

[https://www.techbout.com/disable-web-results-in-windows-search-44034/#:~:text=Disable%20Web%20Results%20in%20Windows%20Start%20Menu%20Search%20Box&text=Right-click%20on%20the%20Search,0%20and%20click%20on%20OK](https://www.techbout.com/disable-web-results-in-windows-search-44034/#:%7E:text=Disable%20Web%20Results%20in%20Windows%20Start%20Menu%20Search%20Box&text=Right-click%20on%20the%20Search,0%20and%20click%20on%20OK).

this white burning eyes background [this here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmIgQ.png)

a image about what i saying exactly [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIXWq.png)

and this is horrible.

i've been trying to solve it for hours but I haven't found a solution, any help? thank you in advance

Comment: I do not recognize the app and it look absolutely and perfectly fine to me.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.